How to fix CORS issue on Keycloak
I am getting this error while trying to access the Token Endpoint:
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:9090/realms/XXX/protocol/openid-connect/token' from origin 'https://localhost:7001' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

My access settings are like in the screenshot, I put * on Web Origins. I don't know what I am missing, it should allow any origin.


Are you supposed to use that endpoint from the client side? What parameters is it getting passed?

I think yeah, I am trying to logout from Keycloak as explained in this post https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/how-is-logout-really-working-and-can-we-bypass-the-logout-confirm-page/15314/4

Just put the app URL "https://localhost:7001" in the Web Origins field. Should solve it.

I got the same error

Are you sure its https since its localhost? Not http ?

Try setting your post logout redirect uri to https://localhost:7001/* . And set Web Origins field to *

Not really the answer to my question, but it is the answer to my initial issue, that is getting the idToken, so I can logout from keycloak.
The way I found is to get it directly from session storage using Javascript:
function getIdToken(key) {
    var strJson = sessionStorage.getItem(key);
    if (strJson != null) {
        var json = JSON.parse(strJson);
        return json.id_token;
    }
    return null;
}

The rest concerns Blazor/.Net developers:
@page "/authentication/{action}"
@using Microsoft.JSInterop

@inject NavigationManager Nav
@inject IConfiguration Configuration
@inject IJSRuntime jsRuntime

<RemoteAuthenticatorView Action="@Action">
    <LogOut>
        @{
            var authority = Configuration["Keycloak:Authority"];
            var redirectTo = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("https://localhost:7001");
            var id_token = getIdToken().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            Nav.NavigateTo($"{authority}/protocol/openid-connect/logout?id_token_hint={id_token}&post_logout_redirect_uri={redirectTo}");
        }
    </LogOut>
</RemoteAuthenticatorView>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string? Action { get; set; }

    private async Task<string> getIdToken() 
    {
        string key = $"oidc.user:{Configuration["Keycloak:Authority"]}:{Configuration["Keycloak:ClientId"]}";
        string idToken = await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("getIdToken", key);
        return idToken;
    }
} 

Works perfect!
